# Does $U^*U=I$ imply $UU^*=I$?

Tags: matrices

Let $U$ be a $n\times n$ matrix with complex entries satisfy
$$
U^*U=I
$$
where the star denotes the conjugate transpose. Can we then deduce that
$$
UU^*=I
$$
?

Comment: Take conjugate from both sides of first equality then you will get the second one.

Comment: No you don't. You get the same equation

Comment: Yes, in any unital ring you have $ab = 1$ implies $ba = 1$, as you can see by first multiplying on the right by $b^{-1}$, then on the left by $b$.

Comment: @Joppy this is not really correct.

Comment: @Cameron Williams - my mistake, I must be getting confused with elements that have two-sided inverses.